How to open an external activity or app (Google Maps) from Compose Multiplatform (Android, iOS)?
I'm building a Jetpack Compose Multiplatform app, and I need to open Google Maps from the app when a user clicks a button. This functionality should work on both Android and iOS.
For Android, I'm aware I can use Intent to open Google Maps, but how can I achieve this within the context of a Compose Multiplatform project for Android and iOS?

What is the correct way to handle platform-specific code for opening
an external app (like Google Maps)?

Are there any Compose Multiplatform libraries or methods to do this
in a more unified way, or should I write platform-specific code for
Android and iOS?


Any examples for both Android and iOS with Compose Multiplatform would be greatly appreciated!
